# How to connect angular2 with sqlserver in visual studio code?

Tags: sql-server, angular, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

I have been working with angular 2 and mongodb but now i want to connect my web app with sqlserver and perform a sample CRUD operation.I am unable to find any documentation regarding the same,any help regarding it will awesome.
Thanks.

Regards,
Hrishikesh k

Comment: its just a matter of host and port? Just make a connection to that host:port.

Comment: You probably need asp.net as the backend. this is similar to the express/rooter/mongoose construct you already know.

Comment: BY searching a little bit, I found also a [OLE for Windows](https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole) for node.js, may be that can be an alternative to connect to MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vscode does not support such functionality by default, however there is an extension for developing Microsoft SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, etc https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql

Inside `vscode` open command palette, select `Install Extension` and type `mssql` then click `install` button.